# Validate n-amount of UITextfields inside UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am running into a "slight" problem using dynamic cells and UITextfield validations.

Due to the fact that the rows get reused the cells dont actually exists in the table view.

Lets say **I have 20 rows**, each as a UITextfield but only **5 are visible** at a time, how would I **validate all** the fields to check if the text entered is correct?

Please help a fellow out

Comment: Keep track of each values when user type in it (look at the `UITextFieldDelegate` method to know what info register).

Comment: Question "how to fill cell that appears again after being disappeared with actual data" is pretty same, and you probably already got solution if your tableView work correctly.

Comment: Use Data Model to keep track of values inputted in UITextfields.

Comment: keep all values in array and check in array... this is what I do...

Comment: You can manage by using Model's Array or dictionary's Array where you can validate key-value Pair.

Comment: Oh yeah...damn my logic. Makes totally sense to store the input in arrays!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the entered data separately in a model object; in your case, a simple array of strings might be sufficient. Whenever a user enters (or changes) a text, set (or update) the respecive array entry; for validation you can then just use your array and ignore the texts in the UI.